# Getting Null Pointer Exception in Selenium WebDriver using TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-eclipse

I am new to Selenium and while running the below script I am getting null pointer exception and test stops running as soon as the site called loads. I am unable to understand the reason for exception.

The code is as given below:

```
package TestNGPackage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;

public class ParameterizationTest {
WebDriver driver;
  @Test(dataProvider="getdata")
  public void Login(String Username, String Password) 
  {
    //WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
    //WebElement username= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("username")));
    WebElement username=driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
        WebElement password= driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
        username.sendKeys(Username);
        password.sendKeys(Password);
        WebElement SignIn= driver.findElement(By.tagName("button"));
        String text = SignIn.getText();
        if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("sign in")) {
            // sign in btn
            SignIn.submit();
        }
  }

  @DataProvider(name="getdata")
  public Object[][] testgetdata()
  {
      Object[][] data = new Object[3][2];
      //row1
      data[0][0]="ho@abc.com";
      data[0][1]="welcome23";
      //row2
      data[1][0]="ho@baskin.com";
      data[1][1]="welcome23";
      //row3
      data[2][0]="ho@nike.com";
      data[2][1]="welcome23";

      return data;
  }

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeTest() {
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

      driver.get("http://52.25.202.63/illweb/");
    //  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

  }

  @AfterMethod
  public void AfterTest() {
      //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement logout = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Logout"));
        logout.click();
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.close();

  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> [TestNG] Running:
>       C:\Users\Ronit\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--473949223\testng-customsuite.xml
>
>     [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\Default suite\Default test.xml
>     [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\Default suite exists: true
>     FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod AfterTest
>     java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at TestNGPackage.ParameterizationTest.AfterTest(ParameterizationTest.java:60)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:216)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:712)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1129)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:746)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1264)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1189)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1104)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1076)
>         at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)
>
>     SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod beforeTest
>     SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod AfterTest
>     SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeMethod beforeTest
>     SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterMethod AfterTest
>     FAILED: Login("manjeet@wtechspaces.in", "p@ssw0rd")
>     java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at TestNGPackage.ParameterizationTest.Login(ParameterizationTest.java:20)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1129)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:746)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1264)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1189)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1104)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1076)
>         at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)
>
>     SKIPPED: Login("ho@baskin.com", "welcome123")
>     SKIPPED: Login("ho@nike.com", "welcome123")
>
>     ===============================================
>         Default test
>         Tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Skips: 2
>         Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 4
>     ===============================================
>
>
>     ===============================================
>     Default suite
>     Total tests run: 3, Failures: 1, Skips: 2
>     Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 4
>     ===============================================
>
>     [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\testng-failed.xml
>     [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output exists: true
>     [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\Default suite\testng-failed.xml
>     [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\Default suite exists: true
>     [TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 36 ms
>     [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@5594a1b5: 30 ms
>     [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\junitreports\TEST-TestNGPackage.ParameterizationTest.xml
>     [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\junitreports exists: true
>     [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@3f3afe78: 15 ms
>     [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@1cd072a9: 228 ms
>     [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@34ce8af7: 8 ms
>     [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite\toc.html
>     [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
>     [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite\Default test.properties
>     [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
>     [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite\index.html
>     [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
>     [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite\main.html
>     [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
>     [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite\groups.html
>     [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
>     [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite\classes.html
>     [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
>     [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite\reporter-output.html
>     [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
>     [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite\methods-not-run.html
>     [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
>     [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite\testng.xml.html
>     [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\Default suite exists: true
>     [Utils] Attempting to create C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old\index.html
>     [Utils]   Directory C:\Users\Ronit\workspace\FirstTestNGProject\test-output\old exists: true
>     [TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@6b71769e: 58 ms

Please help me with what I am doing wrong, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You find a NullPointerException cause driver is not getting initialized before that point. You tried to initialize a WebDriver instance inside beforeTest() method, but it was local. To fix this, just initialize that WebDriver inside the beforeTest() method without redeclaring as:

```
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

not

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

The second NullPointerExpception is caused due to the same reason.

Comment: Yes! Thank you.  And well explained.  This solved my problem.